# Angular before optimized image loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, image

I'm using `NgOptimizedImage` to load images:

```
<img [ngSrc]="imageUrl" fill>
```

And it works, but before it loaded there is just empty room. How can I put there an image before the original loaded?

Is there something like this I can do:

```
<img [ngSrc]="imageUrl" (load)="hideReplaceImage()" (unload)="showReplacementAgain()">
<img [src]="willBeReplaced">
```

**How do I put an image before the original image loaded?**

update: 
with `(load)` event now I can show replacement image and then hide it when original loaded. But if I scroll away from the original image it unloads and then there's an empty space again (empty space before original loads).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've just tried to use image `(load)` event just now and when the optimized image loaded the replacement hides which is correct, but then when scrolling away from the image it unloads. And when it unloads there is empty space again. I'm looking now for something like `<img (unload)="showReplacementAgain()">`